# Large amount of "cached" files even after a fresh reboot

Tags: memory

My macbook pro usually does not have any "cached" data until there are many *many* apps running. So I am surprised to see the following after a reboot - and with no

- IDE's
- browsers until opening this one for SOF
- sizeable background processes (I killed `docker`)

So what might be causing that *8.2GB* of `cached files` ?

[image]

I am on `High Sierra`.

Comment: A file is cached for faster access.  I'm not seeing the problem here...

Comment: I am wondering why this might be happening all of a sudden. It is important to keep tabs to diagnose for those (not infrequent) times the system slows down. I typically run a number of very heavy apps and seeing this without good explanation complicates my understanding of the memory usage/model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cached Files is memory that *was* used, freed (available for other apps) but still has the content available *if* the same program needs it again.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464):

> Cached Files: Memory that was recently used by apps and is now
>   available for use by other apps. For example, if you've been using
>   Mail and then quit Mail, the RAM that Mail was using becomes part of
>   the memory used by cached files, which then becomes available to other
>   apps. If you open Mail again before its cached-files memory is used
>   (overwritten) by another app, Mail opens more quickly because that
>   memory is quickly converted back to app memory without having to load
>   its contents from your startup drive.

**This is not an issue and is working as expected.**

Comment: This is after a fresh reboot - so it is unclear what was "recently used".

Comment: See:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/CachingandPurgeableMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013104-SW1

Comment: I perused that - and am  not seeing how it  relates to an 8GB cache showing up all of a sudden - and after a reboot.

Comment: The cache is stored on the hard disk. It is not volatile and stays in place even after a reboot. You can delete cached files, but the OS makes the files available to be overwritten, as stated before.

Comment: So what I am  reading here is that it should not hurt performance.  I am still short of an answer on why this behavior suddenly occurred: i had not noticed  that on reboot before and am puzzled why in this case.